# AppDelegate.m Facebook and Twitter handleUrl function

Tags: ios, react-native, twitter-oauth, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to add Facebook and Twitter auth to my react-native app at the same time.

According to the official instructions, I need to modify the AppDelegate.m file for handUrl the following way for twitter:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
  return [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options];
}
```

And the following way for facebook.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```

How can I combine the two? I tried to check the variables and decide which one to return however no success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it the following way:

My AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"mirrorapp"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
//  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
  return [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with checking **`url.absoluteString`**

**For Example:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

  //Get absolute string
  NSString *aStrURL = url.absoluteString;

  if ([aStrURL containsString:@"YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID"]){
    // facebook related code here
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];

  }
  else{
    // twitter or other code here
    return [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for url.scheme like this :-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url 
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

  //App opened with Facebook scheme
  if([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID"]){
       return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                           openURL:url
                                                    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                           annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
  }
  //App opened with Twitter scheme
  else if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"YOUR_TWITTER_ID"]){
       return [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options];
  }
  //App opened with different scheme
  else{
      return YES;
  }
}
```